# Find fit for 3D data

Tags: list-manipulation, fitting, built-in-symbols

Consider some dataset in the form `{x,y,data[x,y]}`:

```
dataset = {#[[1]], #[[2]], ToExpression[#[[3]]]}&/@Import["dataset.dat", "TSV"];
(*Data in form (x,y,z,value)*)
dataset1 = 
  SortBy[Join[
    Flatten[Table[{dataset[[i]][[1]], dataset[[i]][[2]], 
       dataset[[i]][[3]][[j]][[1]], dataset[[i]][[3]][[j]][[2]]}, {i, 
       1, 7, 1}, {j, 1, 460, 1}], {1, 2}], 
    Table[{dataset[[8]][[1]], dataset[[8]][[2]], 
      dataset[[8]][[3]][[j]][[1]], dataset[[8]][[3]][[j]][[2]]}, {j, 
      1, 337, 1}], 
    Table[{dataset[[9]][[1]], dataset[[9]][[2]], 
      dataset[[9]][[3]][[j]][[1]], dataset[[9]][[3]][[j]][[2]]}, {j, 
      1, 460, 1}]], {#[[1]], #[[2]]} &];
```

(the file with data may be downloaded via [this link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dwfrzwdol6lfki1/dataset.dat?dl=0)).

I would like to get a fit to the `dataset` in the form $f(x,y,z)$ (where `f` is a scalar function, and z denotes a coordinate from the `data`).

I have come up with a stupid (in the sense that it requires a lot of time and effort) procedure. **First**, I find a data fit for each value of $x,y$ separately, in terms of a function (see also [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/244977/nonlinearmodelfit-works-badly), it is related)
$$
\tag 1 F(z,a,b,c,d) = \frac{a+bz+cz^{2}}{d+z} 
$$

```
FitFunctionz[X_, Y_] := Block[{},
  DataSetSelected = 
   Select[dataset, #[[1]] == X && #[[2]] == Y &][[All, 3]][[1]];
  fit = NonlinearModelFit[
    DataSetSelected, {(a + b x + c1 x^2)/(d + x)}, {a, b, c1, d}, x]
  ]
FitFunctionz[dataset[[2]][[1]], dataset[[2]][[2]]]
```

> FittedModel[(-0.00217617 x^2+0.752673 x+0.0436133)/(x+0.231889)]

**Second**, I parameterized each of the coefficients $t_{i}(x,y) = \{a,b,c,d\}$ in the form of a similar function
$$
\tag 2 t_{i}(x,y) = \frac{\alpha(x)+\beta(x)y + \gamma(x)y^{2}}{\delta(x)+y},
$$
**Third**, $\tau_{i}(x) = \{\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta\}$ are given by the same formula as $(2)$:
$$
\tag 3 \tau_{i}(x) = \frac{\tilde{\alpha}+\tilde{\beta}x + \tilde{\gamma}x^{2}}{\tilde{\delta}+x}
$$
I.e., we have matryoshka:
$$
f(x,y,z) = F(z,t_{i}(x,y)), \quad t_{i}(x,y) = F(y,\tau_{i}(x)) \quad \tau_{i}(x) = F(x,\tilde{\alpha},\tilde{\beta},\tilde{\gamma},\tilde{\delta})
$$
A problem is that this procedure requires a lot of time, as a lot of dedicated steps have to be implemented. **Also, the number of parameters is 64**. Could you please tell me whether it is possible to find fits more straightforwardly in Mathematica, using only $(1)-(3)$?

**Update**
Okay, it seems that I have found the desired fit using NonlinearModelFit.

Comment: I am not clear on your data structure.  Do you have a f(x, y, z) which is a scalar or is the f(x, y, z} a vector? Or perhaps you have a f(x, y) which is a vector?

Comment: @Hugh : thanks, I have updated the question. f(x,y,z) is a scalar function.

Comment: How do I get your data structure into a standard form? For example `NonlinearModelFit` requires data in the form of { {x1, y1, z1, f1}, {x2, y2, z2, f2}...} .

Comment: @Hugh : I've added code `dataset1=` to the question body.